# How can I make it so that the text I'm showing besides these FontAwesome icons doesn't shift when the icon changes?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this sort of custom checkmark I'm trying to do using FontAwesome.

Here is the HTML and CSS style code:

```css
.check {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.check-unselected {
    color: #4E444B
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <i *ngIf="selected" (click)="selected = false;" class="fa fa-check-square purple-1 check"></i>
  <i *ngIf="!selected" (click)="selected = true;" class="fa fa-square-o purple-1 check check-unselected"></i> &nbsp;{{ label }}
</div>
```

Whenever I select and unselect, the text shifts very slightly. When it is selected, it shifts slightly to the right. When it is unselected, it shifts back to where it was. What I want is for the text to remain static and never move. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: purple-1 is just a color property, it doesn't have any size properties that affect it.

Comment: wrap the icon in span and give it a width?

Comment: you could use Grid instead of Flex and define the width of the column with the icon, or set the width of the flex items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping the icons in another element and giving that parent element a fixed width, the icons will stay equally separated from the text. You may want to move the clicked event to the parent element and handle it there.

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div style="width:50px; text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-check-square purple-1 check"></i></div>
    <div style="width:50px; text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-square-o purple-1 check check-unselected"></i></div> &nbsp;{{ label }}
</div>
```

You can use `text-align:center;` to have the icons centered. That way the icons will both align too.